# WCF Error Zero Application Endpoints when using Remote Client

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I have a published WCF Service running correctly and verified by pulling up the wsdl? screen.

However, when I try to access any methods using code from a separate website I get the following error:

> Service 'wcfServiceFromCaps.AgentWebAppServiceClient' has zero application(non-  infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your     application

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IAgentWebAppService
{

[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceData))]
void DoWork();

[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceData))]
String GetAgentPicURLUsingStation(string station);
```

}

Client WebConfig

```
    <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IAgentWebAppService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://myfulladdresshere:87/AgentWebAppService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAgentWebAppService"
          contract="IAgentWebAppService" name="WSHttpBinding_IAgentWebAppService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client CS

```
AgentWebAppServiceClient newWcf = new AgentWebAppServiceClient();

            try
            {

                string newstring = newWcf.GetAgentPicURLUsingStation(this.Phone);
                newpicurl = newstring;
            }
            catch (FaultException<wcfServiceFromCaps.ServiceData> Fex)
            { 
                 ....
            }
```

What am I missing?

Update!****

I resolved it by cleaning everything up and recreating from scratch. 
Now I'm getting the following message:

> Cannot open Database "dbname" requested by the login.  The login
>   failed. Login failed for user "Servername$"

Comment: need to make sure your config is 'configged' correctly.  Check out [this link](http://visualstudio99.blogspot.com/2010/01/wcf-errors-wcf-service-has-zero.html) first, helped me in the past.

Comment: Can you post a safe config you have used in this scenario?